# spacemacs and key chording

Tags: spacemacs, key-chord-mode

I just started using spacemacs, and I would like to achieve the following:
press f then d, and this for example types the word "fraction". I know package key-chord does this, but I think this is not compatible with spacemacs because it key-chord uninstalls when spacemacs is started

Comment: Use abbrev-mode instead.

Comment: I want to kind of hold down f and  flick g.. not press f release f, press g release g..is there any package that achieves this?

Comment: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/2292 suggests the combo can work.

Comment: not clear if you can use evil-escape to do anything but escape? I want to use chording for evoking macros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be installing it using Spacemacs conventions. You should add `key-chord` to `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` in `dotspacemacs/layers`. `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` may already be present in your .spacemacs file, but if not, add it like:

`dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(key-chord)`

Here's an [example](https://github.com/NJBS/dotfiles/blob/master/.spacemacs#L74) of a .spacemacs file that includes `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`.

You may need to restart Spacemacs after adding it, or `SPC f e R` (to reload configuration) may be sufficient. You can find additional documentation on the subject in [this section](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION#without-a-layer) of the documentation.